# How to increase the accuracy of Obj detection yolov7 model trained on landscape or square images and tested on android camera imgs which are portrait?

Tags: python, object-detection, detection, yolo, yolov5

I trained my object detection model on custom data downloaded from google and open-source data available and I am currently using this model for an android phone camera stream but the accuracy is low. one thing that I notice is that my training images are almost all square or landscape images. nut android camera stream is portrait.

- I want to know that when we train the yolov7 model will resize images to 640x640 does it affect the object shape or bounding box position?
- Do I have to convert my android stream to 640X640

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know that when we train the yolov7 model will resize images to 640x640 does it affect the object shape or bounding box position?

During training, when a resize occur, the shape and size of objects, inevitably, changes, but, the bounding box(assumed, annotation bounding boxes), i.e. (x, y, w, h) are being adjusted appropriately with current images size as (1, 1).